# How to design my macro to contain function return value

Tags: c, function, macros

in order to prevent asking a X-Y problem, I'd like to describe my intention first. There are a lot of self-defined structs, all of them are **static singleton variables**. I'd like to design a macro ( or function ) to get the specific address to what I want. Here's what I do so far:

```
/* the struct of apple, banana and cherry have been defined somewhere above
 * BUT NOT YET DECLARED */

const char *fruit_name[3] = {
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "cherry"
};
```

What I expected is that the the user could obtain the pointer to struct simply by offering number, that is, 0 to get the ptr to struct apple, 1 to get the ptr to struct banana and so on.

And I declare the static variable by:

```
#define DEFSTRUCT(struct_name) \
    static struct struct_name my##struct_name(void)  \
    { \
        static struct strcut_name singleton;  \
        return &singleton; \
    }
```

Then I use it to generate 3 functions, which will return the pointer to structs:

```
DEFSTRUCT(apple)    // whenever calls myapple() I got the reference to static struct apple 
DEFSTRUCT(banana)
DEFSTRUCT(cherry)
```

Here comes the most frustrating part, I CANNOT to make a macro ( or function ) to transfer the string to get access to them

Here's what I did, but in vain:

```
#define GETSTRUCT(struct_name) my##struct_name()

void get_fruit(void *ptr, int num) {
    ptr = GETSTRUCT(fruit_name[num]);  // I expect that ptr would points to static struct apple if num is 0;
}
```

However hard I try, the fruit_name[num] WILL NOT be transferred into correct string name,
Is there anyone could specify what mistake I've made ?
Thx a lot

Comment: This whole thing is still an XY problem. It's not 100% clear what you're trying to ask here, but it makes no sense, so your question is the Y part. What is the overall problem you're trying to solve with these singletons and access by number? (Why a number?)

Comment: You misspelled `struct_name` in your `DEFSTRUCT` macro (*`strcut_name`*). `return &singleton;` is a type error. `get_fruit` doesn't do anything: Assigning to `ptr` is pointless because it's a local variable (i.e. destroyed when the function returns).

Comment: Your problem could be solved by: `static struct apple apple_singleton; static struct banana banana_singleton; static struct cherry cherry_singleton; static void *const fruit_mapping[] =  { &apple_singleton, &banana_singleton, &cherry_singleton }; void *get_fruit(int n) { return fruit_mapping[n]; }`

Comment: The comment “the struct of apple, banana and cherry have been defined somewhere above BUT NOT YET DECLARED” does not make sense. A definition is a declaration. Perhaps this comment is supposed to say the `struct` type has been defined, but the apple, banana, and cherry instances of it have not been declared or defined. However, this is not relevant at this point in the code, as the following code merely declares an array of pointers to strings; no `struct` is involved.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for a function parameter `num` to be expanded to its value in a macro expansion or for an element of an array of `strings` to be expanded to its string in a macro expansion. Both of those require evaluation that never occurs in the preprocessor.

A function to return a pointer to a structure can be:

```
struct struct_name *get_fruit(void *pointer, int index)
{
    static struct struct_name ArrayOfTheseThings[] =
    {
        { contents of "apple" struct },
        { contents of "banana" struct },
        { contents of "cherry" struct },
    };

    return &ArrayOfTheseThings[index];
}
```

or:

```
struct struct_name *get_fruit(void *pointer, int index)
{
    const static struct struct_name *ArrayOfPointers[] =
    {
        &NameOfAppleStructDefinedElsewhere;
        &NameOfBananaStructDefinedElsewhere;
        &NameOfCherryStructDefinedElsewhere;
    };

    return ArrayOfPointers[index];
}
```

Comment: Thx for your replying, but I'd like to ask what does the "struct struct_name" mean in your second example? Shouldn't I use const static void * instead ?
Because all of these 3 fruits have completely different data type

Comment: @Shih-ChanHuang: `ArrayOfPointers` could be made an array of `void *`, and `get_fruit` could be made to return `void *`. However, this adds to the indications that you have an X-Y problem. Returning a `void *` is essentially useless to a caller who does not know the type of the object is pointed to. In other words, the caller needs to know whether they have a `struct apple`, a `struct banana`, or something else if they are to do anything with the pointer other than compare it or pass it on to other software.